# Network Ports not visible for "fedora" docker image

Tags: image, unix, docker, containers, fedora

Fedora image has been pulled to my docker server and ran same. But unfortunately ports are not visible for the image. pls assist me (attached image)

thanks
[Docker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbsg3.png)

Comment: please just do a ctrl v, cleanly with `my code ; my error message`, I can't acces the site  linked

Answer (score 1):

You will have to map the ports to the host first :

Try the following :

```
docker run -name=yourname -p 8080:8080
```

Note the -p option.Post this you can see `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp` under PORTS.

Comment: container name is : "firstcontainer" now tell me how can i use above comment and let me know wat to check before allocate port in server